# Filtering an array based on an array of Int

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, arraylist, filtering

I have a `Drink` object that has a property called `strength`. Strength is an Integer with values of 0,1,2 or 3.

Now in my project, I display all of the `Drink` objects in a List View. At the top of the list view, there's a filtering section for the user to filter the `Drink` objects based on strength. These are CHECK BOXES, meaning users can select as little as 1 filter, or as much as 4. This gets saved to SharedPreferences as an Int Array.

```
data class Drink(val theDrinkName:String, val strength:Int)


object DrinkData {

    const val low = 0
    const val medium = 1
    const val strong = 2
    const val intense = 3

    fun generateAllDrinks():Array<Drink> {
        return arrayOf(
            Drink("Vodka", medium),
            Drink("Shirley Temple", low),
            Drink("rum", strong),
            Drink("Gin", medium),
            Drink("151", intense),
            Drink("99", strong)
        )
    }

}
```

Here's how I am generating all of the data:

```
val allDrinks = DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedWith(
    compareBy<Drink> { it.theDrinkName.first().isDigit() }
        .thenBy { it.theDrinkName.toLowerCase() }
)
```

**I need to be able to filter the strength property of this data based on an Int Array.** (An Int Array is what gets saved to SharedPreferences.)

```
val filteredStrengthArray = arrayListOf<Int>(2,3)
```

This would filter `allDrinks` to rum, 151, 99.

**My progress:**

This is the closet I got to achieving this filtering.

```
    val allDrinks = DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedWith(
        compareBy<Drink> { it.theDrinkName.first().isDigit() }
            .thenBy { it.theDrinkName.toLowerCase() }
    ).filter { it.strength == 2 || it.strength == 3 }
```

The problem is I need to filter by an Int Array to align what is saved in SharedPreferences.

**How can I filter the strength property of this data by providing an Int Array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that comes to mind is checking if `strength` property is contained by `filteredStrengthArray`:

```
val filteredStrengthArray = arrayListOf<Int>(2,3)
val allDrinks = DrinkData.generateAllDrinks().sortedWith(
        ...
    ).filter { filteredStrengthArray.isEmpty() || filteredStrengthArray.contains(it.strength) }
```